# How to use SVN and Eclipse in workspace together?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, workspace

I wrote a simple app for Android but now I want to put it into version control.

So I installed Subclipse but there are two problems:

1. My project is in *[workspace]/MyApp* but I want to move it into *[workspace]/MyApp/work/trunk* (where *work* is a SVN working directory)

   I always get the error that I don't must overlap the workspace. I created another workspace and used it with this project - but is that really the best solution?
2. What about branching? I came from Code::Blocks where you can simply move your project file! In Eclipse it's a bit more complicated I think. Is there a refactor/copy solution available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The normal procedure is that you right click on the Eclipse project, and left click on Team -> Share project.  You tell Eclipse where in Subversion you want to store the project.  The Eclipse workspace and the Subversion trunk are different directories.  Sometimes on different computers.

The Eclipse workspace is called the Subversion working copy.  You commit changes from the Subversion working copy to the Subversion trunk (or branch) using Team -> Commit.  You update changes from the Subversion trunk to the Subversion working copy using Team -> Update.

2) To branch in Subversion, you use Subclipse to copy the modules from the trunk to a branch.  Then you check out the branch in Eclipse.

To move modules in Eclipse, you right click on the module and left click on the Refactor -> Move option.

To copy modules in Eclipse, you just copy and paste.  Copied modules and new modules have to be identified to Subversion using Team -> Add to version control.

Comment: Thank you very much! You don't even need Subclipse to copy the modules, just right click and select `Team->Branch/Tag...`. @Windows user: Don't use backslashes in the repository URL!